# Chat keyboard issue in Chrome on iPad Air

Tags: bug, chat, mobile-web

I am able to use chat in Chrome on my iPhone, but for some reason it is unusable on iPad because the input area is invisible.

I can view chat just fine, but when I try to participate, the input area gets obscured by the screen keyboard:

> [image: Chat interface, keyboard overlays input area]

I have a third-party software keyboard, but switching to that by clicking on the globe icon does not help at all. In fact, the Apple keyboard is better in this situation, because it features a paste button on the gray toolbar above the keyboard itself. With that, I can (crudely) work around the problem by preparing a comment in a different tab, and then copy it to the clipboard so I can paste it in the blind here.

> [image: Workaround: paste text via the keyboard's paste button]

Sorry if the images are too big or the text in the images is distracting; I couldn't quickly figure out a way to make them smaller without losing too much context.

iOS 12.4.4, Chrome version information:

```
Google Chrome   79.0.3945.73 (Official Build) stable (64-bit)
Revision        0bf9cea9474e3f92865f8074002d4b1dd9cf806f-refs/branch-heads/3945@{#886}
OS              iOS
User Agent      Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 12_4 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/79.0.3945.73 Mobile/15E148 Safari/605.1
```